# Pyinstaller add icon, launch without console for Mac

Tags: python, console, icons, pyinstaller

This is a really short question. I have created a package for Mac using Pyinstaller and I am mainly trying to add an icon to it. I am also trying to get the program to run without launching the terminal as the user has no interaction with the terminal. Currently I am keeing the following into cmd when running pyinstaller:

> > > python pyinstaller.py --icon=group.ico --onefile --noconsole GESL_timetabler.py

I get the regular package (Unix Executable) and an App. However only the Unix Executable works and the no processes run when I double click the App.

Also, neither the App, nor the Unix Executable, has the icon image displayed. I am sure this is a trivial problem with my command to pyinstaller, but I am having difficulty figuring out the mistake. Could someone help me fix the instructions above? Thank you!

Comment: rename the python file .pyw, thats how you normally stop command prompt running. maybe if you pysintaller that file

Comment: Hey chris, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 4):

You must have `group.icns` file for app in Mac OS

Answer (score 1):

Try using `--windowed` instead. As far as I can tell they're the same thing, but it might do the trick.

As for icons, I've only gotten that to work on console windows. It just doesn't carry over to my main GUI window.